# Why does my MacOS terminal ask for my password every time I start it?

Tags: zsh, sudo, path, macos

I am new to MacOS (and the world of shell), and this started happening after I tinkered with some settings while installing Homebrew. I can get out of this mode and back to the normal zsh shell using "Shift ZZ"... but it didn't ask for my password before I messed up some settings.

Here is what I see when I launch the terminal:

**Header:Terminal -- sudo**

```
Last login: Fri Feb 26 22:23:31 on ttys000
/Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: 
Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile
Password:

    
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/etc/paths" 9L, 49C
```

And, here is what I see after I press "Shift ZZ":

```
Last login: Fri Feb 26 22:30:15 on ttys000
/Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile
Password:
/Users/zohaibzaheer/.zprofile:12: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
zohaibzaheer@Zohaibs-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Comment: Is there a `sudo` command in your ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc ? Also I think the file missing error is because a / is missing in front of Users.

Comment: You need to show us the contents of your `~/.zprofile` for us to be able to conclusively answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Review the contents of your shell's profile file.

- You've got some lines referencing bad paths in your `~/.zshrc`/etc. It looks like you're missing `/` before `Users` so it's a relative path that doesn't exist.
- You've got a line `sudo vi /etc/paths` which I guess you meant to put in your Terminal rather than your `~/.zshrc`.

In your ~/.zshrc, delete those lines or fix the lines to be as desired.